# MySQL split on semicolon in a column to form a new row for each split

Tags: mysql, split, concatenation, group-concat

So I've been given legacy mysql db with data that looks like this:

```
   DATE     |     DATA
2015-04-27  | sample; sample2; sample3
2015-04-28  | sample1; sample4
```

I'm looking to create a new table that would store date/data pairs like this.

```
   DATE     |     DATA
2015-04-27  | sample
2015-04-27  | sample2
2015-04-27  | sample3
2015-04-28  | sample1
2015-04-28  | sample4
```

I've tried looking into user defined split functions, but they all seem to just want to split on a char and return an instance of the splits. I need to keep all instances to put in new table.

So using this: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

I created the split function and have tried altering the return:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(list, ';'),
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(list, ';', pos -1)) + 1),
delim, '')
```

But it requires a third parameter to specify which instance you want to return. Is there a way to return all instances of new rows with the date from left column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
( date DATE NOT NULL
, data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2015-04-27','sample; sample2; sample3'),
('2015-04-28','sample1; sample4');

SELECT * FROM my_table;;
+------------+--------------------------+
| date       | data                     |
+------------+--------------------------+
| 2015-04-27 | sample; sample2; sample3 |
| 2015-04-28 | sample1; sample4         |
+------------+--------------------------+

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT DISTINCT date
              , data
              , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,';',i+1),';',-1)) x 
           FROM ints
              , my_table
          ORDER 
             BY date,i;

+------------+--------------------------+---------+
| date       | data                     | x       |
+------------+--------------------------+---------+
| 2015-04-27 | sample; sample2; sample3 | sample  |
| 2015-04-27 | sample; sample2; sample3 | sample2 |
| 2015-04-27 | sample; sample2; sample3 | sample3 |
| 2015-04-28 | sample1; sample4         | sample1 |
| 2015-04-28 | sample1; sample4         | sample4 |
+------------+--------------------------+---------+
```